# Tag <p> não quebra linha conforme a DIV

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="row tweet">
<div class="col">

    <div class="tweetContainer">
        <p id="tweet">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    </div>

    <br />
    <form>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><small>Remover</small></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Tenho o seguinte acima minha duvida é porque o P dentro da div conforme na imagem não esta se ajustando (quebrando linhas) conforme o normal, obs tenho esse css:
https://gist.github.com/nicollasfeitosa/2d4de32b36fdf3089ba786972c8130ad

Answer (score 3):

Não esta quebrando linha porque seu texto `aaaa...` é visto como uma unica palavra *(ela não tem espaçamento)*. Então via CSS você pode indicar que o navegador deve inserir quebra de linha nesses casos, para isso você pode usar a propriedade [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) veja os exemplos abaixo:

```css
.tweetContainer {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.break-all {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.break-word {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="tweetContainer">
  <p id="tweet">
    <b>word-break: normal;</b> 11111111111111111 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</p>
</div>

<div class="tweetContainer">
  <p id="tweet" class='break-all'>
    <b>word-break: break-all;</b> 11111111111111111 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</p>
</div>

<div class="tweetContainer">
  <p id="tweet" class='break-word'>
    <b>word-break: break-word;</b> 11111111111111111 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</p>
</div>
```